# Finding a function based on properties of improper integral convergence

Tags: integration, analysis

I've been struggling with coming up with a solution to this problem from my Analysis midterm:

Give an example of a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

(i) $0\le f(x)\le 1$ $\forall x \in\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx $ is convergent.

(ii) The volume of the solid which is obtained by rotating the curve $y=f(x)$ around the $x$-axis is finite.

(iii) The integral $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ diverges.

I've tried using some trigonometric functions and but that doesn't seem to work as none of them holds for (i), I also thought about using some of the $1/x^p$ functions and making them into a piecewise function (because none off the p-functions has a convergent integral on $(-\infty, \infty)$)  but that also didn't result in anything substantial. Right now I am just guessing so any hint on how to approach this and other such problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $(i)$ implies that $(iii)$ cannot hold. If $0\le f(x)\le1$ then $f(x)/x\le f(x)$ for all $x\ge1$ so the integral in $(iii)$ must converge.

Comment: Hey I talked with my professor and he Said that there was a mistake and it should be $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)/x$ so If you have any hint about that it's welcome.

Comment: I think $1/(1+x^2)$, $e^{-x^2}$ and $(\sin{(x)}/x)^2$ are all valid examples.